# Tkinter Input/Entry in Python

Tags: python, input, tkinter

So I am trying to when the person clicks on the button I created, to display the text they wrote on the input field but for some reason when I click the button it displays:

```
.!entry
```

And I don't know what I am doing wrong since I am new to python so I wanted to know how to fix this problem, here's my code and thank you since any help is appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()

def print_input():
    text2 = Label(screen, text=input_field)
    text2.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)

text = Label(screen, text="Write to print:")
text.grid(row=0, column=0)

input_field = Entry(screen)
input_field.grid(row=0, column=1)

submit_button = Button(screen, text="Print!", fg="yellow", bg="purple",             
command=print_input)
submit_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
def print_input():
    text2 = Label(screen, text=input_field)
```

to:

```
def print_input():
    text2 = Label(screen, text=input_field.get())
    #                                     ^^^^^^
```

You're telling the text of the label to be set to the Entry widget instead of the Entry widget's content.  To get the content of the Entry widget, use the `.get()` method.

The funky string you're seeing in the label is the tkinter name for the Entry widget.

Comment: ohhhhh, makes a lot more sense now, thank you for your answer since it solved my problem! :)

Comment: Happy to hear it. If my answer solved your problem, please select my answer as the correct answer. And happy coding!

Comment: have to wait 2 minutes ;) btw another problem appeared meanwhile, the input results are being displayed all on top of each other, do you know how to stop that from happening? (screenshot: https://gyazo.com/b8ed1218674eb610c2882b7eba936bae)

Comment: This is happening because your code creates a new Label each time the `print_input()` routine is called. You should restructure your code to only create the Label once, and the `print_input()` routine should only change the existing Label's text, not create a new Label.